# Is the area under the Cantor Lebesgue function a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is the Cantor Lebesgue function, then is the set $\{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : 0\leq y \leq f(x) \}$ Borel ?

Comment: If it helps, you have to work REALLY hard (or be REALLY non-constructive) to get something that isn't a Borel set in Euclidean space. Thus, your gut feeling should be that there is no way that something as explicitly definable as the area under the Cantor Lebesgue function won't be Borel. Of course, this is by no means a proof . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: Cantor's function is continuous, therefore its hypograph is closed in $(\operatorname{domain})\times\Bbb R$. Specifically, that set of yours is $([0,1]\times[0,\infty))\cap g^{-1}(-\infty,0]$, where $g:[0,1]^2\to \Bbb R$ is the continuous function $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$.